# json-server cannot access via local IP

Tags: server, ip, json-server

I'm using `npm json-server` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server). It used to work great for my needs: run a server on my PC and do `GET` requests to local IP (192.168.1.XX). I reinstalled it and now I can do requests only to *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*. Can't do requests to local IP (cmd ipconfig) anymore. I'm getting this error:

[image]

As @fvu mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175246/3595288)

> this means that the server software is configured to listen on the localhost interface only. This is a configuration item and to avoid exposing a potentially unsecure server many server programs come preconfigured to listen on localhost only.

So is there a way to access this server via local IP as long as json-server doesn't have some extra parameters to enable/disable it?

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me.
[this issue for me has been solved with this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304410/i-cant-access-to-data-in-json-server-from-react-native-with-use-of-fetchs-meth/57324994#57324994)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue:

```
json-server --host 192.168.1.XXX my_file.json
```

Using this command, server is deployed on my local IP, and Windows asks for a firewall exception.

Another solution is to switch to [.NET server](https://github.com/ttu/dotnet-fake-json-server) - another **free simple fake server** where I can setup local IP as endpoint.

All it needs to:

1. [install .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows)
2. use CMD commands:

   ```
      git clone https://github.com/ttu/dotnet-fake-json-server.git
      cd dotnet-fake-json-server/FakeServer
      dotnet run [--file] [--urls]

       #like so in my case:
       dotnet run --file_data.json --urls http://192.168.1.192:57602
   ```

Comment: The host argument for json-server is just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: for me it worked in package.json `json-server --host 0.0.0.0 --watch foo.json`  - `$ npm run server` Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Localhost if you will use the same device:

> json-server --watch filename.json

the localhost IP is 127.0.0.1 so, you can access this filename.json by 2 ways, 
either by

1. http://localhost:8000/filename.json
2. http://127.0.0.1:8000/filename.json

In case you want to access the localhost from another computer/mobile device, place the IPV4 address of your computer

> json-server --host 192.168.0.xx file.json

You can also **assign a port number** of your own using this command:

> json-server --host 192.168.0.xx file.json --port 4000

then run it on any device connected with the same network using

1. http://192.168.0.xx:4000/file.json

Finally if you did not understood where did i take this host IP from,
Go to **command prompt > config /all** and look for **IPv4 address**, copy paste that address to this URL, remember that devices should be on the same network to access this IP.

Answer (score 11):

Another option that worked for me:

```
json-server -H 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -w db.json
```

Note: You need to enable port 3000 for TCP/UDP through firewall though. Something like this

```
sudo ufw allow 3000
```

Comment: I think, Control Panel -> Security Center -> Windows Firewall -> Exceptions -> Add Port (or similar)

Comment: Ah great perfect if your host change from ip. This is the best solution 

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method that worked for me. If you start json-server using your local LAN IP (e.g. 192.168.1.45), you can access the server using an IP address (but not localhost for some reason). For example...

```
json-server [insert your JSON file] --host [insert your LAN IP]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

My fake json-server was running on vagrant machine as 192.168.100
and I am using React app to consume it and faced the same issue so I run this command on my vagrant machine (guest OS) and everything works fine after this. i.e. I can access my APIs something like this

```
192.168.1.100/tasks


npx json-server --watch db.json --port 8000 -H 192.168.1.100
```

Here db.json is my data file consisting of JSON
port is 8000
host is 192.168.1.100 which is the IP address of my server/vagrant machine

AND don't forget to allow port on the firewall (Linux)

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Type this in your command line:

```
npx json-server <folder/filename> --port <whatever port you want>
```

I used this, for example:

```
npx json-server api/db.json --port 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use --host 0.0.0.0 it will get your local IPV4 automatically AND -p "SpecifcPort"

Answer (score 0):

In my case

npx json-server --watch fileName --port YourPort

npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).