# I can't access to data in JSON.server from react-native with use of Fetch's method

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have created a simple JSON.server project with the following code:
`npm install JSON-server -g`

I run this server with the following code:
`JSON-server --watch db.json -p 3001 -d 2000`

when I run this server in my browser, it works but when I fetch data from this server in react native, this doesn't work.

my react-native's codes for fetch data from JSON.server:

```
return fetch(baseUrl + "data")
  .then(
    response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      } else {
        //error
      }
    },
    error => {
      var errmess = new Error(error.message);
      throw errmess;
    }
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(dishes => dispatch(fetchData(data)))
  .catch(error => dispatch(dataFailed(error.message)));
```

`fetchData` method:

```
export const fetchData = data => ({
  data: data
});
```

update 1:

this is baseUrl:

```
export const baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.8:3001/";
```

please help me what is the problem.

[I have tried this question but my problem has not fixed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026532/json-server-cannot-access-via-local-ip)

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Shouldn't your endpoint be `fetch(baseUrl + "db.json")` since you are watching that file instead of `dishes`? Is there a `GET /dishes` route available on your server in `db.json`? Might help if you can share error message and routes defined in `db.json`.

Comment: You also set a custom port `3001` instead of default 3000. This needs to be added in `baseUrl` Ex: `http://localhost:3001/<route>`

Comment: I have updated my question. please look at it again.

Comment: I haven't any error. I don't receive any data from JSON.serever. @Clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue was  because of my ip4 address.
as I told before, [I have tried this question but my problem has not fixed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026532/json-server-cannot-access-via-local-ip)

I did  find a way to fetch data from the server.

For those who are facing similar problem.

Steps:

1) Go https://ngrok.com/ and create account

2) Login

3) Go to setup & installation, follow 1, 2 steps.

4)Place the ngrok.exe in a folder of your choosing. Make sure the folder is in your PATH environment variable.

5) Follow step 3 of setup & installation.

6) Open your command prompt and type ngrok http (eg: 3005) and enter. You will get a ngrok url (eg: forwarding http://977ab183.ngrok.io)

7) Make this url (eg: http://977ab183.ngrok.io/) your app baseUrl

8) Open another command prompt pointing to your app directory and run your json server: json-server --watch db.json -p 3005 -d 2000

Answer (score 1):

You would use **localtunnel** to get a server working on both devices:

Install localtunnel globally on your dev machine

```
yarn global add localtunnel
```

Then you use json-server to setup and run a mock server. The following command sets up the mock server on localhost and port 8000

```
json-server --port 8000 ./db.json --watch
```

Next to expose the mock server to the web use localtunnel

```
lt --port 8000 --subdomain application-mock-server
```

The above command will return a URL accessible across Internet of the form

```
 https://application-mock-server.localtunnel.me.
```

Then you plug this URL inside your React Native code base and will be accessible from the application running inside Expo on the mobile.

* Check full article [here](https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app).