# Why I can connect localhost but can't connect IP address?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, networking, webpack

I've init a project using [vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/), and I run `npm run serve`, webpack starts successfully, and shows the infomation:[image]

The Network address is my local ip, obviously. When I access my page with the address http://localhost:8451/, it worked; however, when I visit http://172.18.149.70:8451/, the page just kept loading and nothing shows.

127.0.0.1:8451 also worked.

Why this happened?

Comment: Since it isnt a loopback/local ip(127.0*, 192.168*) you might be hitting your firewall/router which probably isnt setup to allow traffic on that port

Comment: 172.16-31.x.x and 10.x.x.x are local IP's too @PatrickEvans

Comment: you have to make it listen to `0.0.0.0` meaning "All Interfaces". Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175246/9691976